# Getting Users Real IP address using PHP

Tags: php, ip

I want to get the real IP address from users going on my site even if they use a proxy website like hidemyass.com

This is the code I have and thought it worked but I tested it and it doesn't

```
<?php
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
?>
```

I thought this code would work but proxy still bypass it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If someone wants to hide their IP, what gives you the right to need to know it?

Comment: You could try blacklisting proxies, but that would be an enormous ongoing task ;-)

Comment: You'd probably have a better chance asking them for it :)

Answer (score 19):

There is no guaranteed way to get a "real" IP address, if the proxy doesn't want to tell you about it (and any true anonymous proxy *won't*).

Answer (score 6):

You can't.  The info you have is from apache/iis/whatever, and it only knows who is talking to your server, which in this case, is the proxy.  Unless the proxy wants to send along that info in a header, then you won't get it.

X-Forwarded-For is the best you can do, but its not likely an anonymous proxy will send that.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get the "real" IP address for sure unless you implement some sort of authentication protocol at the application layer that encodes the IP address (which is *also* subject to spoofin).

Why is this?

Because the IP data packet can be rewritten arbitrarily by someone "in the middle" who has access to it. E.g., a proxy, router, gateway, etc.

An IP data packet has this structure

```
| stuff | src ip | dst ip  | stuff |
| ....  | 32-bits| 32 bits | stuff |
```

So src ip - those are just bits, remember  - can be overwritten arbitrarily.

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc791.html will give more information.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the proxy puts the real ip address in the headers (common - depending on why the proxy is being used) (generally in some form of "X-something"), then you can only see the ip address of the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
function get_IP_address()
{
  foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
               'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
               'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
               'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP',
               'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
               'HTTP_FORWARDED',
               'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
        foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $IPaddress){
            $IPaddress = trim($IPaddress); // Just to be safe

            if (filter_var($IPaddress,
                           FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,
                           FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE)
                !== false) {

                return $IPaddress;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```