# most reliable way to get ip address of users using php?

Tags: php, logging, ip, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Users Real IP address using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686318/getting-users-real-ip-address-using-php)

I want to log the ip address of anyone who visits my website using a php script to block possible spammers. Is there a surefire way to find and log anyone's real ip address or a most reliable method?

UPDATE: my website only asks users for a password to log in, no username required. If I want to keep my current method of validation, what other methods can I use to block or deter most spammers?

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], you can't block spammers by ip any reliable way

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Function to find real IP address in PHP

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Source:- http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/getting-real-ip-address-in-php.html

Comment: Be advised that X-Forwarded-For may be a comma+space separated list of IPs instead of just 1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For#Format

Comment: Isnt this very dangerous? http_x_forwared can be modified by the client right? Just stick with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Answer (score 1):

As Dagon said, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], at least using Apache.

But then again, it's already in the Apache logs.

Comment: What else can I do to deter or block most spammers?

Comment: recaptcha? requiring Facebook login (and only accepting people with at least 10 friends)? just a couple of things that pop into mind