# It is possible to get network address with PHP?

Tags: php, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Users Real IP address using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686318/getting-users-real-ip-address-using-php)

I have a script on a site that saves some info about a client when he leaves the page. Is it possible to get his network address, for example `192.168.1.154`.

I saw on a forum a discussion about this and they say to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` but it is not working! It shows me my real IP.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by network address? If you mean the mac address, I think it is not possible to get the clients mac at the server side.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the inside local IP of a client if your server is outside the NAT'd network. That would be not only a security risk, but defeat the purpose of NAT.

You can, if you want his local NAT'd IP, run a javascript, [something like this may work](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=242538):

```
function myIP(){
  var yip2=java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
  var yip=yip2.getHostAddress();
  return yip;
}//end myIP

alert("your machine's local network IP is "+ myIP())
```

Comment: question is regarding PHP..!!

Comment: @AlphaMale which it cant be done! Which is why a solution, which WILL work, was offered.

Comment: This doesn't work on my chrome, and on my Firefox I get _your machine's local network IP is 127.0.0.1_ which obviously is not my NAT ip

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Docs http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

If client will visit you from local network you gonna get `192.168.*.*`, otherwise remote ip like `35.88.33.11`

Comment: but that shows me current ip also

Answer (score 2):

**Use this:**

```
<?php  

   echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  //ip of visitor - you need this

   echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];  //ip of server

?>
```

**Using JSON you can also get the client ip by using the following code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Service 1
    $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?",
            function(data){
                alert( data.host);
            }
    );

    //Service 2
    $.getJSON( "http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=?",
            function (json){
                alert( "User ip: " + json.ip); // alerts the ip address
            }
    );

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible serverside.  Address like 192.168.1.154 are not routable so the server doesn't know anything about them.  It may be possible that some routers set the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header, but you shouldn't count on it.  Unless the script is running only on the local network, like Peter Szymkowski suggests.

see https://superuser.com/questions/63124/is-it-possible-to-get-the-nat-ip-address for more info about NAT

Answer (score 0):

I would see which parameter of `var_dump($_SERVER);` displays your network IP.